# Sort GitHub issues by title

Tags: github, github-issues

It doesn't look like `sort:title` or `sort:title-asc` works

Does anyone know of a way to sort within the tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [help page](https://help.github.com/en/articles/sorting-issues-and-pull-requests) it appears not possible.